# Add http security headers in Prometheus config file

Tags: http, http-headers

I want add HTTP security headers Prometheus config file/ Prometheuyml file-
Headers are-
X-content-type-options : nonsniff
X-frame-options : sameorigin

I tried with below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiKH3.jpg)

But it is not working
Can u pls help me with it. How it should be done

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KssXa.jpg)

Currently I am doing like this